# Google Maps - how to make a div expand to contain its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to create a custom overlay that basically just contains a
HTML element (a div in this case) with text in it. The overlay gets
rendered ok but the text is multiline, where I would like it to be one line. Looking into the DOM with Firebug I can see that the computed width for the div parent is 44px,
which is why it can't expand and render the text in one line. Is there any way I can correct this without knowing in advance what the required width for the div is?

Comment: see that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set white-space property of your div to nowrap

```
div.x { white-space:nowrap; }
```